# How to properly manage PPAs just from the command-line

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, software-sources

What are the recommendations for managing other repositories and PPAs without the help of **Software and Updates** GUI.

How to know if a repository/PPA already, - exist - enabled or - disabled ?

How to handle ****.list***, ****.list.save***, ****.list.save.distUpgrade*** files that get filled up in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory?

---

I'm informed about the commands like`add-apt-repository` and `ppa-purge`

Comment: Well, to check what you have, `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`, each `*.list` file in there represents a PPA usually. Check the contents with e.g. `cat`. If the `deb ...` line is commented out with a `#` at the beginning of the line, it's disabled. otherwise, it's enabled.

Comment: @ByteCommander Yup that would do. But what I was wondering is, if there is better easier way to manage those without going over one by one.. command or something that would make life easier.

Comment: I don't think so, but you could write a script... :-)

Comment: You create an alias or small script for this command `egrep -h "^[ |#]*(deb|deb-src) http://ppa." /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | sed 's/^deb/+ deb/g; s/deb /    deb /g; s/http:\/\/ppa.launchpad.net\//ppa:/g;' | sort -k3` not the perfect solution but it may helps